# In a iOS app that supports CarPlay, why the CPBarButtons in the map navigation bar show always monochrome with a light blue color?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, carplay

I am trying to implement CarPlay for my navigation app, and I am experiencing a misbehaviour. Buttons that are instances of CPMapButton have their appearance on the map as expected. Instead, buttons in the CarPlay navigation bar (buttonType image), that are instances of CPBarButton, do not render well. They appear squeezed and always using a light blue color with no detail:

[image]

The icon I am using is the following:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The misbehaviour is in fact normal. By better reading this [link](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/carplay/icons-and-images/custom-icons/), it appears that:

> A custom icon, sometimes called a template, discards color information and uses a mask to produce the appearance you see onscreen in a navigation bar or tab bar.

Sorry for missing it before...